# Border image appears between all the menu items but not at the last one

Tags: html, css, border

I'm using a border image to separate menu items in my nav sidebar. The image appears at the top of all the items but I also want it to appear at the last item's bottom. I tried using `last-child and used center bottom` but then it disappears from the top of the last element and appears at the bottom instead.  Please check this image - i.ibb.co/hBS62fN/Screenshot-1.jpg. And here's my code:

I just want the border-image to appear top and bottom in all four of the items of my `navbar`.

This is what I've tried so far. This code removes the border from the top of contact and places it at the bottom.

```css
    .main-nav {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
    }

    .nav-content {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .main-nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      display: block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .main-nav ul li {
      width: 100%;
      height: 45px;
      background-image: url(../images/borderimage.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center top;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .main-nav ul li a {
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 15px;
      color: #AA9776;
      text-decoration: none;
      /*    background-image: url(../images/menucizgi.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;*/
      float: left;
      height: 23px;
      width: 157px;
      text-align: left;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000;
      padding: 8px 0 10px 45px;
      margin: 2px 0;
    }

    .main-nav ul li a.active {
      color: #AA9776;
      /*background-image: url(../images/menuover.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;*/
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), 0 1px 0 #000;
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), 0 1px 0 #000;
      box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), 0 1px 0 #000;
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
      -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
      transition: 1s ease;
    }

    .main-nav ul li a:hover {
      color: #AA9776;
      /*background-image: url(../images/menuover.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;*/
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), 0 1px 0 #000;
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), 0 1px 0 #000;
      box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), 0 1px 0 #000;
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
      -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
      transition: 1s ease;
    }
  .main-nav ul li:last-child {
      background-image: url(../images/borderimage.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center bottom;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="main-nav">
      <div class="nav-content">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#about" class="active">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#leather">Leather</a></li>
          <li><a href="#leather-goods">Leather Goods</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a demo?  If you inspect the last li, does the style show that the border image is applied?

Comment: Hi. Check this screenshot i.ibb.co/hBS62fN/Screenshot-1.jpg. No border at the bottom of the contact. Now if I use ```last-child``` then the border at the top of contact moves to the bottom. And yes it shows that the border-image is applied

Comment: Here's the screenshot after I applied ```background-position: center bottom``` in ```last-child```. i.ibb.co/0p5j4Dk/Screenshot-2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options that might work:

Try modifying last child to:

```
.main-nav ul li:last-child {
      background: url(../images/borderimage.png) center bottom no-repeat, 
                  url(../images/borderimage.png) center top no-repeat,
}
```

or add this to your existing css:

```
.main-nav ul li:last-child:before {
      background-image: url(../images/borderimage.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center top;
}
```

Not positive it will work without testing it out in a demo.

Comment: Hey, the first one here worked perfectly. Thank you so much, mate.